# Can I use JavaScript's Web Audio Api to convert a song files frequency(pitch)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I am trying to make an online converter that allows a user to upload a song file and change the frequency of the file. Then download their converted file. I have looked into the web audio API for JavaScript and it seems to only be able to create sounds and change that sounds frequency. Can I use it to change an existing file's frequency(pitch)?

Comment: To be clear, you'd like to make the song higher or lower in pitch, as opposed to changing the sampling-rate, correct?

Comment: @enhzflep Yes, most songs today are played in 440Hz. Im trying to have it convert to 432Hz.

Comment: that should work. Create your filter ( alter freq. down ) from web audio examples on metering.   2. use web audio examples ::  https://gersonrosales.github.io/Record-Audios-and-Videos-with-getUserMedia/example_6.html  to connect readstream on result of upload  to the filter above.. 3. filters output can be piped to the http response or pipe to a filesink , the URL of which is returned to user as link to alteration  ... also ref to : https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API  scrl to the end for practical examples